# ARM assembly branch to address inside register or memory

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm wondering in ARM assembly which instruction I can use to branch to an address or label stored in some memory address.

For example, we can use B LABEL to jump to LABEL. But now the destination can only be known during run time, and it is stored in some known memory place, is there something like B [address]?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there something like B [address]?

No. Load the address into a register first, and then use [`BX`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/Cihfddaf.html) to jump to it:

```
@ In this example, R0 points to the address to jump to
LDR R1, [R0]
BX R1
```

You could also load the address directly into `PC` (though I'm not sure if this is valid across all ARM architectures, so consult the relevant reference document):

```
@ In this example, R0 points to the address to jump to
LDR PC, [R0]
```

Comment: Loading PC is actually supported across all versions of the ARM instruction set, but BX isn't. The later instruction didn't exist until the Thumb instruction set was added to the ARM architecture.

Comment: bx is supported from ARMv4T to the present basically the ARM7TDMI to the present, which is everything that the average programmer will see...

Comment: `LDR R1, [R0]; MOV PC, R1` is also a possibility

Comment: `LDR PC, [R0]` is not possible in ARMv8 anymore now that the PC has a dedicated register.

Comment: @CiroSantilli that sucks. Means there is no way to far call without clobbering any registers.

Answer (score 5):

One important design paradigm of the ARM architecture is that only very few instructions can operate on memory, which is potentially a slow operation: only `LDR` and `STR`. So there is no `B [label]` from memory.

For the register part of the question, a good way to answer this kind of question is to look at the instruction summary sections, which group instructions by type. There is one for branch instructions in ARMv7 and ARMv8:

- [ARMv7](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0406/cd/DDI0406C_d_armv7ar_arm.pdf) A4.3 "Branch instructions"

  As mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32305904/9160762 , in ARMv7 you can use `BX register`, and there is also a `BLX register` which sets the return address for a function call.

  From that table, we know which ones use register since only those can jump to "Any" address: those that use immediates have limited ranges as full addresses don't fit into the fixed 4 bytes per instruction encoding.

  [Minimal runnable example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/48678660562e312b5e33e7d1d0e6f8320cf29f80/v7/bl.S).

  Another option in ARMv7 mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32305904/9160762 is to `ldr` into the PC, since PC is just `r15`:

  ```
  ldr pc, [r0]
  ```

  However, this is not possible anymore in ARMv8 where PC has a dedicated register. B1.2.1 "Registers in AArch64 state" says:

  > Software cannot write directly to the PC. It
  >   can only be updated on a branch, exception entry or
  >   exception return.
- [ARMv8](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/ca/DDI0487C_a_armv8_arm.pdf) C3.1 "Branches, Exception generating, and System instructions"

  In that section we learn about `BLR`, `BR` and `RET`.

  `BR` is like `BX`, but without `X` since there is no thumb to worry about.

  [Minimal runnable example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/48678660562e312b5e33e7d1d0e6f8320cf29f80/v8/ret.S).

  The docs then say that `RET` is analogous to `BR`, except that it:

  - gives a hint that this is supposed to represent a function return
  - the register is optional on the assembly, and defaults to `x30`, which is where `BL` puts the return address

Comment: You forgot to mention Thumb-2 mode [TBB/TBH (table branch byte/halfword)](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289912399.htm), which indexes an array of PC-relative offsets and jumps there.  It's for stuff like switch statement jump tables.  `TBB [Rn, Rm]` (so the addressing mode is limited to registers, not a label of course).  The reason ARM doesn't have any other memory-indirect jumps is that it's a load-store machine with a somewhat RISC-like design. And it can't use `ldr r0, [label]` loads except nearby PC-relative or as a pseudo-instruction for multiple instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah thanks, I didn't know about that one!