# Loading function pointer value into a register

Tags: arm64

I want to load a function pointer address into a register so that I can branch to it later since I cannot branch to an address directly according to [ARM assembly branch to address inside register or memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304646/arm-assembly-branch-to-address-inside-register-or-memory)

The function:

```
    void foo(){
        printf("Hi");
    }
```

The function pointer in my case:

```
void* p = &foo; // ex: 0x104ffa7b4
```

**Question** - How I can the store the value `0x104ffa7b4` to register `ex: x4` and then branch to it ?

```
ex: 
   LDR x4, 0x104ffa7b4
   BX x4
```

**Note**: the instructions should be in the form of hex (`ex: ret -> C0035FD6`) in order to be written into memory directly.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: `LDR` is a load, not an immediate move.  But there is an assembler pseudo-instruction `LDR =` to assemble the constant into a nearby literal pool and emit a PC-relative load from there.  You could write `LDR x4, =0x104ffa7b4`, or even `LDR x4, =foo` if linking works correctly.  Or you can write a sequence of three `MOV / MOVK` instructions.

Comment: ```LDR x4, =0x104ffa7b4``` this does not work directly as it's translated to something else in https://armconverter.com, My goal is to achieve a trampoline by patching instructions

Comment: Then use what it is translated to. As @NateEldredge noted, it translates to a load from a PC-relative address.

Comment: I guess since your value fits in 48 bits, the mov/movk approach is just as short and a little easier.  `MOV x4, #0xa7b4 ; MOVK x4, #0x04ff, lsl #16 ; MOVK x4, #0x1, lsl #32`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: 16th Jan 2022 - Solved**
I'm sorry for not presenting the issue clearly, I ended up using keystone assembler and assemble a formatted char string of the below instruction.

```
char *inst[15];
sprintf(inst, "b %p", &foo); 
inst -> b 0x104ffa7b4
```

then I wrote the encoded bytes from keystone to the memory and achieved the jump to foo function.